# is this a good way to do a strcmp to return false when strings are empty

Tags: c++, c, strcmp

I want another condition --still maintaining a  fast execution time but **safer**-- where i return false if either or both strings is empty:

```
int speicial_strcmp(char *str1, char* str2 )
{

    if(*str1==*str2 =='\0')
         return 0;

     return strcmp(str1,str2);

}
```

Comment: no. if you have 100 pairs of strings need to be compared, might only one pair strings of them are both empty. so "if(*str1==*str2 =='\0') return 0;" is not worthy, and moreover 99 pairs have this extra cost now and it just wastes their time.

Comment: do you really want to return zero if only one of the string is empty? Standard strcmp return 0 when the two strings are matched...

Comment: returning 0 means equal - strcmp doesn't ever return false, it returns <0,0,>0 depending on its arguments - what do you want to return?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I mean safe not faster. Question is updated!

Comment: Why should it be safer (if it was correct - I suspect chaining == doesn't work like you expect)? Cannot strcmp really handle an empty string? Perhaps you meant to make it safer by testing whether any of the pointers themselves are NULL?

Comment: yea exactly, son, that's what I want.. yo!

Comment: Then you could check `if (!str1 || !str2) return(-1);` and be done.

Comment: @Michael: Why would you want to say that str1 is less than str2, if either of them is NULL? It is actually hard to tell what would be a reasonable result (other than perhaps asserting).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's not a good way to do it, because it doesn't work.

```
if(*str1==*str2 =='\0')
```

will get evaluated as:

```
bool tmp1 = *str1==*str2;
bool tmp2 = tmp1 == '\0';
if (tmp2)
```

In other words, because the bool will get promoted to an integer, your test will return true whenever the strings start with different characters (`tmp1` will be false, which gets converted to 0, and so `tmp2` becomes true)

Don't try to outsmart the compiler. Writing fast code is not about writing as few lines of code as possible, or even as short lines as possible. Even if chaining together `==` in this manner was meaningful, there's no reason why it'd be faster. Just write code that you understand, and can write correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you implement the early-out tests you suggest correctly, you are very unlikely to make things any faster by doing this sort of thing - `strcmp` will already be doing this or nearly this.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code for `strcmp()`:

```
int
strcmp (p1, p2)
     const char *p1;
     const char *p2;
{
  register const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *) p1;
  register const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char *) p2;
  unsigned reg_char c1, c2;

  do
    {
      c1 = (unsigned char) *s1++;
      c2 = (unsigned char) *s2++;
      if (c1 == '\0')
    return c1 - c2;
    }
  while (c1 == c2);

  return c1 - c2;
}
```

It's already as fast as it could meaningfully be. Your extraneous check only makes the cases you're not interested in, slower.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is the code used. For starters, it's an important-enough function that compiler intrinsics make sense. Otherwise, I'd expect it to be `inline`. The `register` keyword is ignored nowadays, so who'd still use it? And why is there a duplicate return statement? `while(c1 != 0 && c1 == c2);` works too.

Comment: But he wants to return 0 if either string is empty. This code does not meat that constraint

Comment: @MSalters: perhaps whoever wrote it is more suitable to answer your questions. I just copied and pasted the code directly from glibc to prove a point with regard to the OPs need for fast execution. Besides, even his own code has conflicting constraints - he'd better clarify or read the manual entry for `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if( *str1 == 0 || *str2 == 0 )
   return 0;
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant to `return 0;` here? The questioner wants to return 'false' (I take, that means 'not equal') in case either or both of the strings are empty. If you want to keep the strcmp semantics, you should probably only `return -1;` or something else than 0 (which means 'the strings are equal` as far as strcmp is concerned).

Comment: Except that the originator's code returned 0 in the special case? So I don't think we can know what he meant by 'false'

Comment: @Frerich: what Douglas said.. ;P

Answer (score 1):

The example you've given won't even run correctly. `strcmp()` will stop at the first differing characters. If both strings are empty, as satisfied by your "special case" above, this will be handled just as quickly as the example you've given.

By adding a special handler for both strings empty as above, you've only made the cases where they aren't, correspondingly slower.